# ActionScript : Adding value to object name?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Struggling to find the answer. Right so I have a variable which is storing a number, and I have a movieclip called "note". I want to add the number onto the end of the note while adding it to the stage. Any suggestions please ?

```
   var num = 1;        

   addChild(note);     // Should be note1
```

Edit: Thanks for all your help, i've solved the solution. What I have done is created an array for of the movieclips and used a for statement to go through all of the movieclips.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var num = 1;
var cl:Class = getDefinitionByName("Note"+num) as Class;
addChild(new cl() );
```

Comment: Thanks for your response i appreciate it. I'm getting an error saying note1 is not defined. But earlier in my file I have var note1:Note1;  so surely I have already defined ?

Comment: is it Note1 or note1? see the difference of capital "N"?

Answer (score 1):

If `note` here is the name of your class (AS linkage), and you want that your instance be called `note1`, for example, your code can be like this :

```
var num:int = 1;

this['note' + num] = new note();
addChild(this['note' + num]);
```

Hope that can help.